# How to loop through functions in Swift?

Tags: ios, loops, swift

I know that's likely a stupid question, but I'm trying for several hours already and can't do it. So, I'm making a simple game. I have 4 functions for death of my hero. Each of them is performing a different animation so I want program to know who exactly killed a hero. My logic is to put that functions into the array but Xcode tells me that I have a "missing argument for parameter #1 in call". I ignored that and tried to make a switch statement. But every 'case' has an error that tells me that it's expecting a pattern. Here is my code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    dead()
}

var deathArray:Array = [eatenByMouse(), eatenByCat(), eatenByHamster(), eatenByRabbit()]

func dead() {
    switch deathArray {
    case :
        eatenByMouse()
    case:
        eatenByCat()
    case:
        eatenByHamster()
    case:
        eatenByRabbit()
    default:
        cookie
    }

}
```

It's probably an extremely simple problem but I'm new to this and don't know what to do.

I think it's a good idea to post more related samples of my code. I think, my problem could be in collisions. So I have a ColliderType:

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case Cookie = 1
    case Rabbit = 2
    case Mouse = 3
    case Hamster = 4
    case Cat = 5
}
```

Then I'm making a physic bodies for hero and enemies:

```
    self.cookie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.cookie.size.width / 2))
self.cookie.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.cookie.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue

self.mouse.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.mouse.size)
self.mouse.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.mouse.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
```

Sample of eatenByMouse() function:

```
func eatenByMouse() {
    self.groundSpeed = 0
    self.cookie.hidden = true
 let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.mouseArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)
    self.mouse.runAction(animateAction)
}
```

I hope it will clear something maybe. 
It seems to be so easy problem, I'm ashamed that I don't understand it.

Comment: That `switch deathArray` does not look right to me (actually the whole `switch` statement looks funny).  It looks like you want to provide an index into the `deathArray ` to run the corresponding action, but I don't see any reference to an index value.

Comment: Well, I thought that it is the best way to loop thru 4 functions. I have no index for that functions. Obviously I was wrong. But I still don't know how to do it! Ive no index for that functions.

Comment: How do you determine how your hero died (i.e. type of death)?

Comment: didBeginContact = death in my case if I understood you. Hero dies if he touches one of four enemies.

Comment: I updated the code, maybe it will help more. That's how I determine death of my hero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you can determine the type of death in `didBeginContact`. So you need to determine the index for the type of death here and then pass that to the `death` function so it can find the function reference and execute it.

If your death type functions take arguments or return a different result you will need to change the type of the array accordingly.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // You will need to determine this index based on the type of contact/death.
    var deathIndex:Int = 0 // Index of the type of death (e.g. eatenByMouse in this case)

    dead(deathIndex)
}

var deathArray:Array<() -> ()> = [eatenByMouse, eatenByCat, eatenByHamster, eatenByRabbit]

func dead(deathIndex: Int) {
   deathArray[deathIndex]()
}
```

Comment: Full disclosure I don't have access to a compiler right now so I may have a syntax error, I have not used much Swift before.

Comment: So I tried this. The only problem I have now is in the `deathArray[deathIndex]()` It says that it's an 'Array' and it's not convertible to 'Array<T>'.

Comment: For some reason, as I understood, it doesn't like accessing functions by Integers. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I've added the function type to the array

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't worked. Now it's showing me an error "() is not a subtype of 'PlayScene'". That's my name for that scene.

Answer (score 2):

On line 5, you're defining your array of functions:

```
[ eatenByMouse(), eatenByCat(), ... ]
```

Those expressions with the `()` syntax actually invoke the function and resolve to it's return value. Try by just using the function names but not invoking them.

```
[ eatenByMouse, eatenByCat, ... ]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for that! It removed my first problem. But what about patterns?